# How do I install the latest .NET 6 (x86) version using winget

Tags: .net, winget

Using winget to install .net 6, say with command:

"winget install Microsoft.DotNet.DesktopRuntime.6"

always installs the x64 version. How do I install the x86 version?

I tried various winget search, or winget list such as:

"winget search dotnet" or "winget search 86", nothing helpful comes out

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "-a x86" seems to work, so the command would be:

"winget install Microsoft.DotNet.DesktopRuntime.6 -a x86"